# How do I make dynamic 2D collisions faster in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Currently I'm working on a 2D game with destructible terrain in unity. It works great! Except for one thing.... collision generation... Since the terrain is destructible, I have to generate collisions on the go. I tried and it's awful performance. From 1000 fps from editing the terrain to 1 fps when I enable collisions generation. This is a huge issue and I know it's possible within unity because this guy :
https://forum.unity.com/threads/wip-nimbatus.221798/
created it with collisions as well. I tried contacting him but no response yet! Any of you guys have any ides on what I can do? Thanks!

Comment: Could you please add some of the relevant code so far?

Answer (score 0):

I found a rather annoying but working solution to the issue. So basically what was wrong was I was setting points as vertices. The guy I messaged told me that at the time when he made his game, the 2D engine wasn't a thing in unity so he was forced to use regular 3D components. I didn't want to do this because it would possibly limit what I can do with 2D packages since I am not using the 2D engine. But in the end I decided that unless I could find a extremely fast edge finding algorithm that supported concave meshes WITH holes, I would need to just use the regular Unity3D MeshCollider component. I'm not sure why I was having an issue with the Polygon collider as I thought it would work the same as the MeshCollider but in 2D. I think the issue was I was setting the path of the Polygon Collider as each vertice. This is wrong because I think I would need to set the edge vertices only. (My mesh does not share vertices so I'm not sure how to find the edges) Of course I could re write it to share vertices but I think I will be find with the 3D components (For now at least)